# to[List] on a generic HList after Partition

Tags: scala, shapeless

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@ import shapeless._
import shapeless._
@ case class A(); case class B(); case class C()
defined class A
defined class B
defined class C
case class Stuff(a: List[A], b: B, c: List[C])

@ def stuffs[H <: HList](hl:H)(
  implicit
  pb:Partition[H,B],
  pa:Partition[H,List[A]],
  pc:Partition[H,List[C]],
  tl: ToTraversable[H, List]
  ):List[Stuff] =
  hl.filter[B].to[List].map {
   b =>
     Stuff(
       a = hl.filter[List[A]].to[List].flatten,
       b = b,
       c = hl.filter[List[C]].to[List]flatten
     )
  }
Compilation Failed
Main.scala:374: could not find implicit value for parameter ts: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable[pb.Prefix,List]
hl.filter[B].to[List].map {
               ^
Main.scala:377: could not find implicit value for parameter ts: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable[pa.Prefix,List]
     a = hl.filter[List[A]].to[List].flatten,
```

I understand that some evidence is required for the `to[List]` in the result of `hl.filter[B]`, `hl.filter[List[A]]`, and `hl.filter[List[C]]` which would be `pb.Prefix`, `pa.Prefix`, and `pc.Prefix`, but those cannot be used on the same argument list, so not sure what can be done here

Update based on Jeremy's response:

well this works:

```
@ def stuffs[H <: HList, Prefix <: HList, Suffix <: HList]  (hl:H)(
    implicit
    pb:Partition.Aux[H,List[A],Prefix, Suffix ],
    prefixToTraversable: ToTraversable[Prefix, List]
    ) = hl.filter[List[A]].to[List]
defined function stuffs
@ stuffs(List(A()) :: List(A()) :: B() :: HNil)
res30: List[List[A]] = List(List(A()), List(A()))

@ def stuffs[H <: HList, Prefix <: HList, Suffix <: HList]  (hl:H)(
    implicit
    pb:Partition.Aux[H,B,Prefix, Suffix ],
    prefixToTraversable: ToTraversable[Prefix, List]
    ) = hl.filter[B].to[List]
defined function stuffs
@ stuffs(List(A()) :: List(A()) :: B() :: HNil)
res33: List[B] = List(B())
```

but this doesn’t, which makes sense (it’s still weird that it allows to define the function but it fails when trying to use it):

```
@ def stuffs[H <: HList, Prefix <: HList, Suffix <: HList]  (hl:H)(
    implicit
  pa:Partition.Aux[H,List[A],Prefix, Suffix ],
    pb:Partition.Aux[H,B,Prefix, Suffix ],
    prefixToTraversable: ToTraversable[Prefix, List]
    ) = (hl.filter[List[A]].to[List], hl.filter[B].to[List])
defined function stuffs
@ stuffs(List(A()) :: List(A()) :: B() :: HNil)
Compilation Failed
Main.scala:375: could not find implicit value for parameter pb: shapeless.ops.hlist.Partition.Aux[shapeless.::[List[cmd1.A],shapeless.::[List[cmd1.A],shapeless.::[cmd1.B,shapeless.HNil]]],cmd1.B,Prefix,Suffix]
stuffs(List(A()) :: List(A()) :: B() :: HNil)
      ^
```

then I tried this:

```
@ def stuffs[H <: HList, PA <: HList, SA <: HList, PB <: HList, SB <: HList]  (hl:H)(
    implicit
  pa:Partition.Aux[H,List[A],PA, SA ],
  pb:Partition.Aux[H,B,PB, SB ],
  prefixToTraversableA: ToTraversable[SA, List],
  prefixToTraversableB: ToTraversable[SB, List]
    ) = (hl.filter[List[A]].to[List], hl.filter[B].to[List])
Compilation Failed
Main.scala:380: could not find implicit value for parameter ts: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable[pa.Prefix,List]
  ) = (hl.filter[List[A]].to[List], hl.filter[B].to[List])
                            ^
Main.scala:380: could not find implicit value for parameter ts: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable[pb.Prefix,List]
  ) = (hl.filter[List[A]].to[List], hl.filter[B].to[List])
                                                   ^
```

That last snippet makes sense to me, so why does not work?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the output types of a shapeless proof, you can use the proof's corresponding `Aux` type with an additional type parameter to get a proof for that output type in the same parameter list:

```
def stuffs[H <: HList, Prefix <: HList, Suffix <: HList](implicit
  pb: Partition.Aux[H, B, Prefix, Suffix],
  traversablePrefix: ToTraversable[Prefix, List]
  ....
)
```

Most proof types have an `Aux` type for just this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your last attempt was quite close. @Jeremy was right about needing type variables for the output types of the `Partition` operations. You also need to specify the output types of the `ToTraversable` operations to determine the element type of the results of the conversions,

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist._, ops.traversable._

case class A()
case class B()
case class C()
case class Stuff(a: List[A], b: B, c: List[C])

def stuffs[H <: HList, PA <: HList, SA <: HList, PB <: HList, SB <: HList, PC <: HList, SC <: HList](hl:H)
  (implicit
    pa: Partition.Aux[H, List[A], PA, SA],
    pb: Partition.Aux[H, B, PB, SB],
    pc: Partition.Aux[H, List[C], PC, SC],
    prefixToTraversableA: ToTraversable.Aux[PA, List, List[A]],
    prefixToTraversableB: ToTraversable.Aux[PB, List, B],
    prefixToTraversableC: ToTraversable.Aux[PC, List, List[C]]
  ): List[Stuff] = {
    val as: List[A] = hl.filter[List[A]].to[List].flatten
    val bs: List[B] = hl.filter[B].to[List]
    val cs: List[C] = hl.filter[List[C]].to[List].flatten 
    bs.map(Stuff(as, _, cs))
  }

val hl = List(A(), A()) :: B() :: List(C()) :: B() :: List(C(), C()) ::HNil
val ss = stuffs(hl)
val expected =
  List(
    Stuff(List(A(), A()), B(), List(C(), C(), C())),
    Stuff(List(A(), A()), B(), List(C(), C(), C()))
  )

assert(ss == expected)
```

Comment: Nice, I think I finally understood the Aux now. I gotta say, as with everything with shapeless so far, the principle is simple once understood.